# Chrome still displays website as "not secure" despite Root-Ca being added to trusted certificates?

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, ssl, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I have a very simple Apache 2 server which hosts a website. I wanted to add the secure HTTPS protocol and created a certificate chain using this tutorial: https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/introduction.html (I skipped the CRL part, also didn't install CRLs on Apache)

I configured my Apache server and installed my certificates and it works. When I visit my website via https://, it shows the full certificate chain. Of course, Google Chrome still displayed the website as insecure because it doesn't trust the Root-CA. So I added my self-signed Root-Certificate via Chrome settings (imported the .pem file into "trusted root certificates"), however, my website is still displayed as insecure.

When I click the red warning icon, it says, that the certificate is "invalid", however when I inspect each certifcate individually, it says it's valid. When I check the list of trusted Root-CAs I can also see my Root-CA there.

I tried to add the intermediate certificate into the intermediate certificate set via Chrome settings, but that also didn't work.

I tried to troubleshoot for some time on similar forums but didn't find anything relevant to my situation. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Chrome? It has an UI bug related to the URL bar not updating when trust status changes.

Comment: @user1686 Yes, I did try that, I also restarted my computer, but that didn't help either

Comment: I just checked on Firefox; after installing the Root-CA in Firefox, it works just fine. So there is something specific about Chrome that doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your CA certificate into Chrome trusted Root-CAs,
not the SSL certificate which goes into your web-server.

See the ultra-highly-voted post
[Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate).

The recap from the accepted answer:

> 1. Become a CA
> 2. Sign your certificate using your CA cert+key
> 3. Import `myCA.pem` as an "Authority" (*not* into "Your Certificates") in your Chrome settings (Settings > Manage certificates > Authorities > Import)
> 4. Use the `$NAME.crt` and `$NAME.key` files in your server

That answer also contains the `openssl` script for
becoming a Certificate Authority.

Comment: I did create a Root-CA. I did not add the Server-Cert to Chrome but the Root-CA.

Comment: The other answers in that post may also help. Is a specific error code returned when browsing to the site? Is the validity period longer than one year? In general, it's really hard to make yourself a CA. If you don't want to pay, you may use a service like LetsEncrypt and generate ssl certs for free by using ZeroSSL.com, SSLForFree.com, etc.

Comment: I did precisely as instructed but Chrome still says the connection is not secure. Has anyone got any other suggestions?